# How change a Node Position using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a problem with the XML Web response i am getting. The Inner Loop warehouseItems have a node leadTimeCumulative and leadTimeDays coming on the first and Second Position for the FIrst time, for the Rest its coming last. I need to keep these node always in the Last position in side the Loop.

Example

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <searchItemResponse>
      <status>
        <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
      </status>
      <itemList>
        <itemWithWarehouses>
          <item>
            <originOfData>SME</originOfData>
            <itemNumbers>
               <shortNumber>115632</shortNumber>
               <tssArticleNumber>PT0401450-T46N</tssArticleNumber>
          </item>
          <warehouseItems>
             <leadTimeCumulative>14</leadTimeCumulative>
             <leadTimeDays>14</leadTimeDays>
             <warehouse>
               <code>GA01</code>
             </warehouse>-
             <stockItem>-
                <quantities>
                   <quantityAvailable>0</quantityAvailable>
                   <quantityOnHand>0</quantityOnHand>
                </quantities>
             </stockItem>-
             <stockClass>
                <group>MTO</group>
             </stockClass>
          </warehouseItems>-
          <warehouseItems>-
             <warehouse>
                <code>GL01</code>
             </warehouse>-
             <stockItem>-
                <quantities>
                   <quantityAvailable>0</quantityAvailable>
                   <quantityOnHand>0</quantityOnHand>
                </quantities>
             </stockItem>-
             <stockClass>
                <group>MTO</group>
             </stockClass>
             <leadTimeCumulative>14</leadTimeCumulative>
             <leadTimeDays>14</leadTimeDays>
          </warehouseItems>-
          <warehouseItems>-
             <warehouse>
                <code>GS01</code></warehouse>-
             <stockItem>-
                <quantities>
                  <quantityAvailable>0</quantityAvailable>
                  <quantityOnHand>0</quantityOnHand>
                </quantities>
             </stockItem>-
             <stockClass>
                <group>MTO</group>
             </stockClass>
             <leadTimeCumulative>10</leadTimeCumulative>
             <leadTimeDays>10</leadTimeDays>
             </warehouseItems>-
        </itemWithWarehouses>
      </itemList>
    </searchItemResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I need any XSLT for changing the position of the node leadTimeCumulative and leadTimeDays to the Last like the rest of the Loop Structure. Please help me.

The above part is solved.
I need an improvement along with this.The tssArticleNumber node need to copy to the respective warehouse items with a different node name like "Item No". Please give me another XSLT for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- this is called an identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- a template to override warehouseItems -->    
    <xsl:template match="warehouseItems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- apply templates except leadTimeCumulative and leadTimeDays -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::leadTimeCumulative) and not(self::leadTimeDays)]|@*"/>
            <Item_No><xsl:value-of select="../item//tssArticleNumber"/></Item_No>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="leadTimeCumulative"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="leadTimeDays"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have one more requirement Joel, Please help me.

Comment: There is node called tssArticleNumber. I need a copy of this node with a Node "Item No" in the WarehouseItems.

Comment: In cases like this, you should formulate another question. But if I find time today, I'll look into this.